# Isn't the use of the integrity attribute *specifically for official Bootstrap CDNs* superfluous?

Tags: security, cdn

I understand what the integrity attribute is for and I quote:

> [...] using CDNs also comes with a risk, in that if an attacker gains control of a CDN, the attacker can inject arbitrary malicious content into files on the CDN [...]

But let's be real, how likely is it really that an attacker would "gain control of a CDN" in the case of the official Bootstrap CDNs which are:

https://code.jquery.com

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com

What's the likelihood of an attacker gaining control of any one of those 3 CDNs for any length of time?

I understand that using the integrity attribute, in general, would make sense. But does it really make sense for those 3 CDNs that official Bootstrap uses?

Comment: A CDN offers hackers a one-to-many avenue: If they can compromise (for example) jQuery's CDN they suddenly have access to tens of thousands (if not more) websites to spread malicious code. Likelihood is irrelevant; it's about additional layers of security.

Comment: I would argue that there is no value to any potential attacker in changing the contents of a framework css file that's being served up to thousands of different websites. So, an integrity check is definitely superfluous there. JavaScript is, of course, a different matter.

Comment: CSS might not provide the same scope of dangers as a JavaScript hijack, but it can certainly cause turmoil across the 100,000+ sites that rely on something like Bootstrap's framework.  Integrity ensures that in the event that the CSS is compromised at least you aren't serving up something unintended; imagine if someone hijacked Bootstrap and modified every `.col` to serve up a background image of pornography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The art of war teaches us to rely not on the likelihood of the enemy's not coming, but on our own readiness to receive him; not on the chance of his not attacking, but rather on the fact that we have made our position unassailable.*
>   - Sun Tzu, ancient Chinese general

It is never wise to rely safety on the unwillingness or disability of the enemy (hacker in this case) to attack your resources. You need guarantee. If you are right that you are safe and you use an extra layer of security, then you are using that layer, however, if you do not have that extra layer, then your statement about your safety comes under the real test. And if, for any reason the test will show that you are wrong, that could be catastrophic for you and your clients.

Comment: When it comes to JavaScript files, then yes, a guarantee of file integrity is a good thing. Changing the contents of a CSS file that's being served up to thousands of *different* websites would be completely useless to any attacker thus making the integrity check superfluous. At least in the case of framework css files. If an attacker gets access to a js CDN, he can change any css via JavaScript anyway. Changing css alone (without JavaScript) is useless to an attacker. No attacker who can manage to hack a major CDN will waste that ability on changing the background color of websites.

Comment: @WebDevBooster let's suppose you have a very popular website and the CSS you are using "for some reason" is modified in a highly undesired manner, changing the colors, hiding crucial elements, etc. In this case you will have some losses in the popularity of your website, possibly financial losses. For instance, if background image paths are changed to pornography images, then you are the victim of a spam attack, but will lose AdSense ads along the way...

Comment: As I see it, the only reason for changing the css alone would be for LOLs. If an attacker wants to target/damage one particular website, then targeting the css CDN would be highly inefficient and stupid. No attacker with the skills required to hack a major CDN is that stupid. If thousands of websites got trolled via this attack, none of them would lose AdSense because Google would recognize this as just a temporary attack. No substantial damage is to be expected from such attack. It would always get fixed very quickly, probably in a matter of minutes. Just a minor temporary nuisance, no more.

Comment: * Just a minor temporary nuisance, no more.*  ... I'm not sure how this is an argument against `integrity`? If you can *prevent* this with a single attribute declaration what is the argument against doing so?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I don't think I am qualified to give an opinion about the psychology of a hacker, first, and foremost, because I am not a psychologist and secondly, because every hacker is a different person. So I will avoid doing so. However, when it comes to integrity, the important thing is to make sure that there is no possibility of doing a breach, rather than leaving security leaks and arguing about the mental health of those who might use those. If a big penis becomes the background of a perfume site of hundreds of visitors per second, then it will lose some users in 2 such minutes...

Comment: CSS can link any URL as a resource (e.g. for a background image). Just having the ability to do that for a thousand websites means you have a huge DDoS network on your hands. Don't even take this as a definitive answer - it's just an example ... even the seemingly most innocuous things can be turned into weapons with some creativity.